# php: Get file extension from corrupted file

Tags: php, file

I have a few files that somehow lost their extension due to a bug in a script. So now, I have a folder with many files like "image" or "123" instead of "image.jpg" or "123.pdf". By using finfo, I can grab the mime type. Is something similar in php also possible for the extension so that I can repair them somehow? (It is only the file name - the files didn't get damaged)

I could - of course - create a huge array with possible file types. But this approach is not "safe" enough as there are many file extensions with the same MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Create new directory `recover..`

and try this...

```
<?php

$fp = opendir("files/");

$typeDetect = array(
    "filename" => "type",

);

while($file = readdir($fp)){
if(array_key_exists(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), $typeDetect)){
    echo $typeDetect[pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] . "<br/>";
    if(copy("files/" . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME), "recover/" . pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "." . $typeDetect[pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] )){
     echo "Success";
    }
}else{
    echo "File not exists";
 }
}

?>
```

Add filename and type in the array `$typeDetect` and execute

This should work...

Comment: With this apporach, I need to find all possible file names and add them to the array, right? (I have so many possibilities that this cannot be done. I hoped it could be done by some php function that reads a file and tells me which extension would fit best)

Answer (score 0):

finfo_file() might help you to get the extension of the corrupted file.

Refer to the following code of line :

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename) . "\n";
}
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: I don't really think this will help me - look at application/excel: it has about 12 possible extensions, so it is impossible to guess which one is the right...